# Integrating Active Directory with third party LDAP

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, embedded-linux

We produce these Linux-based appliances we'd like to integrate with Active Directory.

I'm wondering if the following workflow is possible:

The client installs our device, gets it on the network.  The Windows SysAdmin uses something from their standard toolset to add our appliance as a resource which has custom abstractions regarding permissions and rights.

From the appliance's point of view; by virtue of the SysAdmin configuring the AD server (and thereby connecting to it), the Linux appliance would be able to use that server as the authentication agent without the Windows SysAdmin having to directly interface or configure the appliance.

So basically, it's a plug-in solution that can add new abstractions, specific to our tech, by the AD server somehow connecting and authenticating to it.

I have no real experience managing and configuring AD for corporate IT so I don't know if this is possible in the slightest.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Plug in solutions that work in all AD situations are practically nonexistent! It's usually a bit of sysadmin work to get it going.

Your appliance needs to ask for a number of fields like server address, server port, use SSL, proxy agent (app name and app DN), proxy password, base DNs and proxy pattern.

Then your appliance app, Java or PHP or whatever, needs to implement the LDAP protocols and just do the authentication check.

I've integrated corporate LDAP with both Wordpress and Mediawiki (before they had plugins for it), and it was pretty straightforward, just not plug and play.

I have two files I use in PHP for this - one with settings, the other with the auth function. Include both of those in any PHP app and just pass the input username and password, and it returns authenticated with info about the user like name, email, etc...

Here's a test page I created when I first got it all working.

```
<html><body>
<?php

# Matt Hart - PHP-based authentication against active directory
# Tested on Fedora Core 4 with Apache 2.0.54, PHP 4.3.11, OpenLDAP
# OpenSSL, php-ldap
# Working on RHEL4

echo "<br>Attempting Secure LDAP Connection<br>";

// $mh_ldaphost = "ldaps://directory.yoursite.com:636";
$mh_ldaphost = "ldaps://ldap.yoursite.com:636";
$mh_ldapconn = ldap_connect($mh_ldaphost) or die ("Failed");
echo "<br>Succeeded ... Testing app binding<br>";

# Bind using app credentials
$mh_appid = "yourappid"; // ****** Use your application id
$mh_dn = "uid=" . $mh_appid . ",ou=Apps,o=Yoursite.com";
$mh_bind = ldap_bind($mh_ldapconn, $mh_dn) or die("Failed");
echo "<br>Succeeded ... Get user corp ID</br>";

# Get the user's corporate ID
$mh_search = "ou=employees,ou=people,o=yoursite.com";
$mh_userid = "johnny"; // ****** User ID to find
$mh_filter = "(uid=" . $mh_userid . ")";
$mh_search = ldap_search($mh_ldapconn, $mh_search, $mh_filter) or die ("Failed");
echo "<br>Succeeded: ";
$mh_entries = ldap_get_entries($mh_ldapconn, $mh_search);
$mh_corpid = $mh_entries[0]["corpidfield"][0];
echo "CorpID=" . $mh_corpid;

# Authenticate the user
echo "<br><br>Authenticating...<br>";

$mh_authdn = "corpidfield=" . $mh_corpid . ",ou=employees,ou=people,o=yoursite.com";
$mh_authpass = "Depp1"; // ****** User password
$mh_authbind = ldap_bind($mh_ldapconn, $mh_authdn, $mh_authpass) or die("Failed");
die("Success");

?>
</body></html>
```

You can also print the whole entries[] array to see what all it is possible to return.

Comment: Is your solution open source?

Comment: Added the code from a sample page I created. You can see from the app versions how old it is! But it still works fine on PHP5 and the latest Active Directory servers.